# Multi level user login - Android Studio / Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to create a multilevel user login page for Android Studio, I have a working basic login. I added user levels to the database but my application keeps crashing. I'm using Android Studio and Firebase as backend.

Login.Class

```
private void checkUserType() {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserProfile userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
            int userType = (userProfile.getUsertype());

            switch (userType) {
                case 0:
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, DoctorActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

This is what my database looks like:

[image: This is what my database looks like.]

Logcat:

> Process: com.example.trixiavillarama.hope, PID: 5524
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.trixiavillarama.hope.Login.checkUserType(Login.java:124)
>           at com.example.trixiavillarama.hope.Login.checkEmailVerification(Login.java:116)
>           at com.example.trixiavillarama.hope.Login.access$300(Login.java:26)
>           at com.example.trixiavillarama.hope.Login$4.onComplete(Login.java:91)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:23)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: can you post your database structure on how you are storing those different users?

Comment: I updated the post. @GastónSaillén

Comment: If your application crashes, there should be an error message and stack trace in the logcat output. Can you look those up, and add them to your question?

Comment: Post updated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, it looks like you are getting started with SO and you have done a great job editing your question to help us help you. I would just suggest that you check out [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference()' on a null object reference

Because your `firebaseDatabase` object is `null`, you forgot to initialize it. To solve this, please add the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Right before the following line of code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
```

Comment: The app won't crash now but it won't redirect to a different page if I use an admin acct and vice versa

Comment: This sounds basically as another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.